# Access my Ubuntu from a flash drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, remote-access

I have the following situation:
My main Ubuntu that is installed on PC's ssd won't boot because of 'dev/sdb2 clean' black screen I can't get through.

I installed a new test Ubuntu on my flash drive. I can now at least access my main Ubuntu's files from this Test Ubuntu as a partition but my question is How can I access my Main Ubuntu's console so that I can interact with it, e.g to run
`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and try to fix my main Ubuntu boot problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main Ubuntu system is not running (because there can be only one OS running at a time, and you are running your test Ubuntu system and not the main one), so there is no console you can access.

To perform the operation you mentioned (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`) you don't have to "access console of your main Ubuntu" (which makes no sense), but need to *change root* of your filesystem. Normally, when you access your main Ubuntu partition from test system, it is *mounted* under some path, which means, the root of your partition is accessible under `/some/path/name` (you have to determine what is the actual pathname, I just use some placeholder), and the directory that would normally be `/etc` if your main Ubuntu were running, is accessible under `/some/path/name/etc` (the same for other directories like `/bin`, `/usr` etc.)

You must identify what is the actual `/some/path/name` mentioned above and type the following command which *changes root* to that path:

```
sudo chroot /some/path/name
```

Changing root means that the partition that was previously available under `/some/path/name` will now be visible as the actual root of your filesystem (`/`), *as if you were running your main Ubuntu system* (while you're actually still running the test system). So the `/etc` directory from your main Ubuntu will now actually be `/etc`, and so on. In that state, commands that modify various system files like `apt-get`, will modify files on your main Ubuntu system and not on the test one - which is probably what you need.

(BTW. if you type `exit` when working in changed root, you return to your original state, where your main Ubuntu system partition is again available under `/some/path/name`. You should do this when you are done.)

Comment: Thank you. It worked but unfortunately it didn't resolve my main problem.